# unable to read xml file within project folder using AJAX request

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax

Iam trying to read a simple xml file i placed my xml file in project root folder but still when im accessing the xml file it says 404 not found i dont know why if nay one know please help me.

this is the content in my NewFile.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CATALOG>
<CD>
<TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
<PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
<YEAR>1985</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
<PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
<YEAR>1988</YEAR>
</CD>
</CATALOG>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="loadxml()">Load xml Document</button>
<div id="display"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadxml(){
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechage = function(){
        if(this.readyState==4 && this.status==200){
            myfunction(this)
        }
    };
xhttp.open('get',"NewFile.xml",true);
xhttp.send();

}
function myfunction(xm){
    var i=0;
    var table = "<tr><th>Artist</th><th>Title</th></tr>";
    var x = xm.responseXml;
    var cd = x.getElementsByTagName("CD");
    for (i = 0; i<= cd.length;i++){
        table += "<tr><td>" + cd[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue  + "</td><td>"  
        + cd[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</td></tr>";
    }
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = table;


}
</script>
</html>
```

[this is my project path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltdNw.png)

Answer (score 0):

Well if you're on a *nix system then "NewFile.xml" is not the same as "newfile.xml".  If not that then I'd guess the root of your project is not where you think it is.  In a lot of frameworks the root for static files is in a subdirectory with a name such as "public"

Based on that screenshot it looks like your xml file is in the parent directory above where your index.html file is.

Comment: hello @Momus my file name is NewFile.xml  and please look at my proj structure here https://postimg.org/image/mjyme5bp9/

Comment: Well like I said in the edit to my answer, it looks like the xml file is in the directory above index.html.  "NewFile.xml" is a relative path from index.html so the xml file would need to be in the same directory.

Comment: Thankyou @Momus now that error got cleared but when i click on load xml document button it returns nothing ..

Comment: thanks there are couple of spelling mistakes i cleared it

Comment: Open a console in your browser and then add console.log(xhttp.responseText); inside the onreadystatechange block of your code to see what's being loaded.  You could also add a console.log() inside the if statement to make sure it's succeeding, and inside myfunction to make sure it's getting called.

Comment: Cool.  Glad it's working.  Don't forget to mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

NewFile.xml is not accessible from the path you have entered. 
From what I NewFile.xml is in the outer folder. 
You can try

```
xhttp.open('get',"../NewFile.xml",true);
```

Comment: Thankyou  now that error got cleared but when i click on load xml document button it returns nothing

Comment: thanks there are couple of spelling mistakes i cleared it